# React, observer stateless component with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observable, mobx

Im having some problems using React with TypeScript and now Im stuck with making a stateless component an observer. Im using MobX btw.

StatelessComponent:

```js
const TaskItem: React.SFC<{task: Task, deleteTask: (e:any) => void}> = (props) => (
        <li onClick={ props.deleteTask }>{ props.task.name }</li>
);
```

Code below gives type missmatch assigning ClassicComponent to StatelessComponent and im getting nowhere solving it.

Error:
[ts]
Type 'ClassicComponentClass<{ task: Task; deleteTask: (e: any) => void; }>' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{ task: Task; deleteTask: (e: any) => void; }>'.

```js
const TaskItem: React.SFC<{task: Task, deleteTask: (e:any) => void}> = observer((props) => (
        <li onClick={ props.deleteTask }>{ props.task.name }</li>
));
```

How do I make a stateless component an observer? And is there a "prettier" way to write this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this works:

```js
const App = observer((props: {test: string}) => 
    <div>{props.test}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App test="sdsdfsddddddddddddddddddf" />
    ,document.getElementById('root'));
```